# What is the proper way to write this?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

I want to know what is the proper way to write this sentence:

> This document explain how to add, edit, delete questions and answers.

Most corrector tell me there is an error

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Proofreading requests aren't on-topic for this site. [Lang-8](http://lang-8.com/) would be a better place to get help. There is more information in the [Help Center](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) about what types of questions are on-topic here and [what makes a good question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thank you. I will have a look at Lang-8. I come from SO and I tough this was the right site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This document explain**s** how to add, edit, **or** delete questions
>   and answers.

The present tense of "to explain" is "explains" and without the logical use of "or", it would seem to mean that all three actions "add, edit, delete" were to be performed at once.